# Disprove $\dim (A \otimes_k B)= \dim (A)+\dim(B)$ for local noetherian rings $A,B$ with residue field $k$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be local noetherian rings with residue field $k$. $A,B$ contain the residue field $k$ as a subring. I want to find a counterexample to the statement $$\dim (A \otimes_k B)= \dim (A)+\dim(B).$$

The statement is true when $A, B$ are of finite type. In that case, one can use Noether Normalization to make $A, B$ finite $k[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]$-module and finite $k[y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m]$-module, respectively. Then the tensor product of polynomial algebras injects into $A \otimes_k B$, which is further finite over the tensor product. Therefore we conclude, $$\dim(A \otimes_k B) = \operatorname{trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(A \otimes_k B)) = n+m =  \dim (A)+\dim(B).$$

However, it is not sure if the case is true for $A, B$ that are not finitely generated. I don’t think this is true, but I cannot think of any easy counter examples. For a simple example, let $A = \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}_p[[y]]$ be two ring of formal series with finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then it is obvious that $A, B$ are local noetherian rings with residue field $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Note that $$\dim(A\otimes_k B) = \dim(\mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]) =2= 1+1= \dim (\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]) + \dim (\mathbb{Z}_p[[y]])= \dim (A)+ \dim (B).$$

Comment: I've cleaned up your MathJax a bit - `\dim` should be used for $\dim$, and `\operatorname{trandeg}` for $\operatorname{trandeg}$ and similarly for other things that don't already have preset commands. Let me also point out a few mathematical issues: it is very difficult for local rings to be of finite type without being dimension zero, and $\Bbb Z_p$ does not contain any field as a subring.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but does $\dim_k$ here refer to dimension as a $k$-vector space? And $\dim$ to Krull dimension?

Comment: sorry it should all mean Krull dimension. That was a mistake

Comment: I would advise not using $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to denote the field with $p$ elements in a question which is about local rings. The conflict with the $p$-adic integers is distracting. You should probably use $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{F}_p$, or some other non-ambiguous notation.