# $\dim(A \otimes_k B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

This is actually quite a famous problem, found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191667) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399722) on SE.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated $k$-algebras over a field $k$. Show that
> $$\dim(A \otimes_k B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B).$$

Here, $\dim$ denotes the Krull dimension.

I actually almost have a complete solution, but fail to show that $k[X_1, \dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_m] \to A \otimes_k B$ is an injection where we already know that $k[X_1, \dots, X_n] \hookrightarrow A$ and $k[Y_1, \dots, Y_m] \hookrightarrow B$ are finite ring embeddings by Noether normalisation.

What I tried is the following: We know that $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ is finite and hence flat as a $k$-module. Thus we can tensor the injection $k[Y_1, \dots, Y_m] \hookrightarrow B$ with $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ to obtain the injection
$$k[X_1, \dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_m] \cong k[X_1, \dots, X_n] \otimes_k k[Y_1, \dots, Y_m] \hookrightarrow k[X_1, \dots, X_n] \otimes_k B.$$
But how do I show that
$$k[X_1, \dots, X_n] \otimes_k B \hookrightarrow A \otimes_k B$$
is an injection? As far as I know, $B$ is not necessarily flat, so we cannot do the same trick as above.

Comment: $k$ is a field, so every $k$-module is free, and hence also flat

Comment: @AndrewHubery Wow, I'm stupid (every $k$-module is in fact a $k$-vector space which admits a basis). Thanks a lot.